# Multi-sort in Dailymotion API search

Tags: sorting, dailymotion-api

I have to do a multi-sort search in the Dailymotion API, since I am not getting good results with the following queries:
https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=id,title&search=test&sort=relevance
https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=id,title&search=test&sort=visited

I want to combine both the queries...
I have tried using:

sort=visited,relevance

but it gives the following error:

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":400,
      "message":"Unrecognized value (visited,relevance), allowed values are (  
         recent, visited, visited-hour, visited-today, visited-week,  
         visited-month, commented, commented-hour, commented-today,  
         commented-week, commented-month, rated, rated-hour, rated-today,  
         rated-week, rated-month, relevance, random, ranking, trending, old,  
         live-audience  
      ) for `sort' parameter",
      "type":"invalid_parameter"
   }
}
```

Please point me in the correct direction!

Answer (score 1):

The Daily Motion REST API doesn't appear to permit multi-field sorting (at least not as of the time of this answer.)

[https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-sort-filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCcz5.png)

[image]

Comment: that's true, multi-field sorting is not possible. Try to think how much of a tricky question it is (how would you sort by both recent and rated-hour? how would you balance weight due to recentness and to rate in the sort? also, how could you sort by both recent and random? too awkward combinations!)